# Tooltips either not appearing or not disappearing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have been trying to get Bootstrap tooltips to work.  Below is my code in Rails 5.2.

In Version 1, when the button is disabled, tooltips does not work.  However, if I wrap the disabled button in a span, tooltips appears on hover, but when the cursor moves away, it intermittently disappears, but not always. Most of the time it does not.

Please help, I have been working on this all day.

Here is a JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f486veo7/2/

#### JS

```
 $('[data-toggle="tool-tip"]').tooltip();
```

#### Version 1:

```
    tag.button  id: "save-search-btn-disabled",
                class: "btn btn-outline-primary disabled",
                disabled: true,
                style: "display: none",
                'data-toggle':"tool-tip", 'data-placement': "top", 'title': "Your limit was reached" do
      "Save Search"
    end
```

#### Version 2:

```
   tag.span class:'btn p-0',
          'data-toggle':"tool-tip", 'data-placement': "top", 'title': "Your limit was reached" do
    tag.button  id: "save-search-btn-disabled",
                class: "btn btn-outline-primary disabled",
                disabled: true,
                style: "display: none" do
      "Save Search"
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
You should also add `pointer-events: none;` style to the inner (disabled) button. This makes element to be transparent to its parent for input events.
**EDIT**

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#tooltips) says:

Invoking tooltip when the target element is `display: none;` will cause the tooltip to be incorrectly positioned.

To add a tooltip to a `disabled` or `.disabled` element, put the element inside of a `<div>` and apply the tooltip to that `<div>` instead.

By the way: your question states style `display: none` and your fiddle has style `display: inline`

Comment: I apply the tooltip after I display it, so good observation, but not the cause, as the JsFiddle does not work even when display: inline.

Comment: @user2012677 just one more thing: see edited answer

Comment: Pointer was helpful, I also needed to change from inline to inline-block.